# Fitting LOESS function in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting, data-modeling, loess

How can I modify the `method=` argument in ggplot so to customize my `loess` function?

Right now this is my code without implementing a function:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", fill='darkred', level=0.90)
```

And this is the function I would like to implement under the `method=` argument:

```
loess(Y ~ X, data=data, span=0.08, degree =1, family = 'gaussian')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass arguments to `loess()` via the `method.args` argument of `geom_smooth()`:

Edit following comments:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span=0.08, fill='darkred', level=0.90, method.args=list(degree =1, family = 'gaussian'))
```

Comment: Use `formula` and `span` as `geom_smooth` arguments

Comment: In the end I used this code: ```geom_smooth(method = "loess", fill='darkred', level=0.95, span = 0.08, method.args=list(degree=1, family = 'gaussian'))``` because under ```method.args```, ```span``` was not being recognized